# Derivative of Lagrangian does not depend on x?

Tags: optimization

Consider the following problem:
$$
\min \mathbf{c}^T\mathbf{x}, \mathbf{x} \in \mathbf{R}^N\\
\mathbf{A}\mathbf{x}=\mathbf{b}
$$
where $\mathbf{A}\in\mathbf{R}^{D \times N}, \mathbf{b}\in\mathbf{R}^D$.

I am trying to find the Lagrangian and then the dual. I wrote down:
$$
L(\mathbf{x},\mathbf{\lambda},\mathbf{\nu})=\mathbf{c}^T\mathbf{x} + \sum \lambda_i(\mathbf{a}_i^T\mathbf{x}-b_i)
$$
where $\mathbf{a}_i$ are the rows of the matrix $\mathbf{A}$. Then the derivative would be:
$$
\mathbf{c}+\sum\lambda_i\mathbf{a}_i
$$

But this does not depend on $\mathbf{x}$. I am almost sure I made a mistake somewhere in the derivative. How can I find the dual if I cannot replace it in the Lagrangian?

Comment: For the dual you have to minimize the Lagrangian over $x$. The Lagrangian is linear in $x$. What do you get when you minimize a linear function?

Comment: I get a constant which is what I got here. But then what? Do I set $x$ to $0$?

Comment: the question wasn't "what do you get when you derive a linear function"

Comment: I get negative infinity?

Comment: unless the linear function is constant

Comment: Ok I see but now I need to replace $x$ in the Lagrangian. The $x$ that minimizes that would be either infinity or negative infinity depending on the slope of the function. The lagrangian becomes negative infinity now. How can I solve that to get an $x$ that satisfies my constraints

Comment: you do need to replace $x$, you need to find the value of the lagrangian. And that value is $-\infty$ if $c+\lambda_i a_i \neq 0$.

Comment: Thank you for your answers. It still does not answer my question of how to find $c^Tx$. For example if we have a ridiculously easy problem e.g $\min x: x=2$. I would get the derivative of the lagrangian to be $1+\lambda=0$. Solve for $\lambda$, replace that in my lagrangian and that would give me $L=2$ which is of course the answer to my problem. Here $L$ becomes $-\infty$. I don't think $c^Tx$ is negative infinity, is it?

Comment: The dual is $\min_x x + \lambda(x-2) = \min_x -2\lambda + (1+\lambda)x$. You cannot solve anything for $\lambda$; the optimization variable is $x$. The minimum is either $-2\lambda$ or $-\infty$.